# VBA finding like values from a range and pasting

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and only understand basic principles so this might not be possible with the code I have used. I have some code for finding a value in Sheet1 using a range from Sheet2, which pastes entiore row to Sheet3. How could I modify it so that it will still paste the row based on a like value and not an exact match, so would paste the row if "Company Ltd" was in Sheet1 and just Company was in the range. I have tried wildcard statements but can't get them to work with a range. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Option Compare Text
    Sub Find_Values()
    Dim c1 As Range, rng1
    Dim c2 As Range, rng2
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Set rng1 = Range("sheet1!a1:a10")
    Set rng2 = Range("sheet2!a1:a10")


    For Each c2 In rng2
    For Each c1 In rng1

    If c1 = c2 Then
    c1.EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("sheet3").Activate


    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("a" & lastrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

    Next c1
    Next c2

    End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Sam was trying to say is modify this line:

```
If c1 = c2 Then
```

You can use:

```
If InStr(c1,c2) > 0 Then '...
```

You can also use

```
If InStr(c1,c2) > 0 or InStr(c2,c1) > 0 or UCase(c2) = UCase(c1) Then '...
```

Etc.

There are a lot of different comparisons you can add to this line of code.

Making both values uppercase is a good way to do comparisons if you are just interested in the value.

You can also change your code (quite significantly) to use the find keyword which allows you to use wildcards and search using xlWhole and xlPart

It really depends on what the differences are and how much code you want to change.

You might also be interested in using the [Like Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx), although if you're simply comparing values, it is probably not what you need.

Comment: Same warning as on the Sam's answer: Make sure you include the 1st parameter `InStr(1, c1, c2)`, not `InStr(c1, c2)`

Comment: Actually, you don't have to; try it. The first parameter is optional and if you use a string as the first and second it is ignored.

Comment: Method signature is `InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )`, `[ ]` denotes optional.

Answer (score 0):

To find if a string exists within another string, use the [InStr function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php). For example,

```
Dim stringPosition As Integer
stringPosition = InStr("Company Ltd", "Company")

If stringPosition > 0 Then
' we found a match
End If
```

Comment: Thank you but there would be too many variables to hard code in like that and wouldn't know what the structures were like. Could a specific number of characters be matched?

Comment: This is just a sample, in practice you would iterate over each cell in the range, typically with a for or for each loop, then perform your comparisons against the cell value rather than the hard coded value in the above example.

Comment: Don't forget the first parameter for InStr, the starting point.  Your link goes to VB.net documentation

Comment: @Sobigen InStr's first parameter is optional `InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )`

Comment: Apologies, looking closer all four parameters are in optional brackets on my intellisense though without a substring I don't know how much good it would be.  It does "work" with just one string and returns 0.  I thought I had errors with that at some point but I guess it was something else.